# Cost of ID3D11DeviceContext state calls with same input consecutively?

Tags: c++, performance, graphics, direct3d

This goes for any DX11 state call, whether it's `XXSetConstantBuffers` or `IASetVertexBuffers` etc...
Essentially what is the cost of doing the following:

```c
ctx->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 2, constBuffers);
ctx->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 2, constBuffers);
ctx->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 2, constBuffers);
```

Is this essentially just the same as the following?

```cpp
ctx->VSSetConstantBuffers(0, 2, constBuffers);
```

Take the following website [here](https://developer.nvidia.com/content/constant-buffers-without-constant-pain-0) table 1 states that `XXSetConstantBuffers` is worth 114 CPU cycles. It strikes me that there would be little to no overhead in just checking the current pointer value that is set, and only doing those operations if the values are different. It seems to be highly important functionality also, for example if I set a vertex buffer at program initialisation, I can then re-set that vertex buffer at the beginning of each frame to **make sure**, but as far as the GPU is concerned the vertex buffer only actually gets set at program initialisation.

Also, I can do:

```c
//for the sake of example, assuming only one vertex buffer is ever set.
ID3D11Buffer* vBuffer;
UINT stride, offset;
ctx->IAGetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &vBuffer, &stride, &offset);
if (vBuffer != pointerToBufferIWantToSet)
{
    UINT newStride = 8 * sizeof(FLOAT), newOffset = 0;
    ctx->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &pointerToBufferIWantToSet, &newStride, &newOffset);
}//dont set vertex buffer if already set
```

But this seems fishy, If this causes the CPU cycles to be avoided I feel like all DX code should do this, but no one does. So, therefore I feel it's important to ask:

- Does the driver handle it?
- Is there overhead in calling the device context 'getter' methods?

If the answer to both the above questions is 'no' then the best method seems to be to make my own state object wrapper, which seems like an unnecessary amount of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only general answer I can give for your first question is: "It depends."
As far as I am aware of, Direct3D11 does not track the state of its pipeline in order to avoid redundant state changes.

Some vendors might choose to implement such feature in their drivers, but I wouldn't count on that. It's best to assume, that calling the same method thrice will cost thrice as much as calling it once.

Regarding your second question: Yes, there is an overhead*. Whenever you call a DirectX method provided a context switch occurs (switching from the applications context to the drivers context), which takes time.

Most render engines I've seen, memorise the current state of the context, which, paired with render call sorting, proofs to be quite efficient.

---

(*) This is based on my knowledge from lectures regarding operating systems and computer graphics. It might either not apply for Direct3D11 and/or be outdated.

---

EDIT: Addressing the question in comment, since it doesn't fit into an comment.

**Q:** Can you elaborate on 'render call sorting'?

Changing the state frequently causes its penalty. Therefor we want to reduce the amount of state changes required.

Let's think a bit about the broader picture. Before you issue any draw call, you'd usually bind your buffers, shaders and so on. So, for each draw call, we have a state (or configuration) assigned to it. We can represent that state using a tuple of state objects, like this:

```
vertex_buffer a;
index_buffer b;
shader c;
shader d;
render_target e;

pipeline_state state{a, b, c, d, e};

// Then later use...
set_pipeline_state(state);
render_amazing_stuff();
```

Now let's assume, we want to draw 3 objects, with a slightly different configuration.

```
vertex_buffer a, b, c; // a stores the first model, b the second, ...
index_buffer f, g;

shader c;
shader d;
render_target e;

pipeline_state state1{a, f, c, d, e};
pipeline_state state2{b, f, c, d, e};
pipeline_state state3{b, g, c, d, e};
```

We have 3 pipeline states, that only differ slightly. We can either increase our performance by reordering the draw calls by their pipeline state, in order reduce the difference between them.

```
set_pipeline_state(state1); // Set initial state, with all buffers..
render();
set_pipeline_state(state2); // Binds only the new vertex buffer; since it's the only difference.
render();
set_pipeline_state(state3); // Binds only the new index buffer; since it's the only difference.
render();
```

The difference between all state is minimal, reducing the amount of state changes, effectively giving an increase in frames per second.

Comment: Can you elaborate on 'render call sorting' a quick google didn't prevail. Are you talking about draw calls?

Comment: @nedb See my edit; didn't fit into a comment.

I know, that I am not always to best to explain (or articulate) concepts. I dug up a [blog post](http://realtimecollisiondetection.net/blog/?p=86), that explains it quite well.

Answer (score 0):

So, I dug up an old question on the GameDev stack exchange that
can be found [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/88114/how-to-change-render-states-only-when-necessary) this is a very similar question. Here's an excerpt, it's the accepted answer:

> PSGetShader (and in general, all state getters in D3D) are not intended to be called at high frequency. You should do dirty state tracking, and you should implement it yourself. Using PSGetShader will at a minimum create the additional overhead of the AddRef which you don't need for dirty state tracking.

I think this coupled with Julian's answer, results in a fairly clear message, that an application developer should **not** assume that state tracking is handled by the driver.